# unique incremental number for online system

Tags: c#, sql-server

Our client wants us to develop a web-based invoicing system. The generated invoice number will be incremental, for example INV001, INV002, INV003 etc. This invoice number would be generated on the fly, after each request by its user.

The problem we're facing is, how do we generated a totally unique incremental number for each user? There could be 100 of users accessing the website and requesting an invoice at the same time.

Regarding suggestions of using the database incremental number solution, this is my scenario:

The client organize many events at the same time, and for each event, the invoice number should start at 1, and increment 1 by 1. The table will hold plenty of data from various events, so obviously I can't rely on the incremental number column. Here's an example of how the table may look like (with column ID as the incremental column):

```
id | eventName  | guestName 
1  | run for it | john doe
2  | run again  | jane doe
3  | run again  | the rock
4  | run for it | miow
5  | run again  | hohoho
```

so for the scenario above, how do I generate an invoice number INV001, INV002 for event 'run for it', and invoice number INV001, INV002, INV003 for event 'run again'?

thanks

Comment: [Microtime?](http://php.net/manual/en/function.microtime.php). It doesn't completely solve the problem, but it's a start.

Comment: What about the obvious solution of using a database? identity column in sql server or whatever it's parallel in MySql is the best solution for these things

Comment: What is the data storage? you can increment a number in a thread safe way in c# with `Interlock.Increment` but you realy need to back this with a database and have some locking on the database. Or, for SQL (or other DBs) you can use an identity col and just prefix with INV in the UI.

Comment: Assuming you've some form of sql database driving this use a sequence.

Comment: MySql? Sql Server? Oracle? asp.net? php?

Comment: @ZoharPeled mssql and c#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Separate your events from your guests. have an events table that will hold event id and event name, and a guests table that will hold event id, guest details and a guest id (incremental number). this way you can use guest id as the base for your invoice number (you will still need to format it to get INV001, INV002 etc'). Here's an illustration:

```
TblEvents
---------
Event Id (int, incremental)
Event Name (string)

TblEventGuests
---------
Event Guest Id (int, incremental) -- This will be the base for your invoice number.
Event Id (int, FK to events) 
Guest Name (string)
```

### Update

You can use [ROW_NUMBER](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) function to get the results you want:

```
SELECT EventGuest_Id, Event_Id, ROW_NUMBER() OVER 
(PARTITION BY Event_Id ORDER BY EventGuest_Id) AS InvoiceNumberBase
FROM TblEventGuests
ORDER BY Event_Id, InvoiceNumberBase
```

Next time, try not to simplify the question too much. I'm sure you would have got the answer sooner if your question would have been more accurate.

[Try it yourself in this sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/336b80/3)

Comment: Actually this is how my database is designed.. the table for events and guests are separated. I just simplified it for questioning purpose,  because I think the end result is still the same. For your solution, yes, eventGuestId would be incremental, but it will still store data for guests from multiple events. So how do I make it so that the EventGuestId can produce incremental number for each separate events?